# Variable dropped while still borrowed at end of main

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I've been playing around with the `inkwell` LLVM bindings and ran into a problem where the borrow checker complains that a variable is "dropped here while still borrowed" although the borrow has already ended. I've distilled the code down to a pretty minimal example:

```rust
use inkwell::{context::Context, module::Module};

pub fn f<'ctx>(_module: &'ctx Module<'ctx>) {}

fn main() {
    let context = Context::create();
    let module = context.create_module("foo");
    f(&module);
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `module` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:8:7
  |
7 |     let module = context.create_module("foo");
  |         ------ binding `module` declared here
8 |     f(&module);
  |       ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
9 | }
  | -
  | |
  | `module` dropped here while still borrowed
  | borrow might be used here, when `module` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `Module`
```

What I don't understand is why the borrow checker claims that `module` is still borrowed at the end of `main`. Who is borrowing it?

When I change the type of `f` to

```rust
pub fn f<'ctx, 'a>(_module: &'a Module<'ctx>) where 'ctx: 'a {}
```

everything works fine. I find this quite surprising.

Moreover, I could not reproduce the problem with small-ish type definitions. It seems like the types in `inkwell` interact in a specific way that causes this problem. Is this a well known issue? If so, what are conditions for this problem to happen?

Many thanks, M.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, don't specify lifetime parameters if you don't have to. This would work just fine:

```
pub fn f(_module: &Module<'_>) {}
```

The reason using the `'ctx` lifetime in both places is a problem is because `Module` is *invariant* over that lifetime, meaning it can't be shortened at the compiler's will. In addition, lifetime parameters are by construction longer than (or equal to) the lifetime of the object with that type.

Thus you are telling the compiler that you want to borrow `module` for a `'ctx` which is defined to be at least its entire lifetime. This may be fine if the type doesn't have drop logic, but `Module` does and thus needs to mutably access itself at the end of its lifetime. But since the borrow to `f` already requested the entire lifetime, you get a conflict and thus a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the definitions of `create_module`:

```
    #[inline]
    pub fn create_module(&self, name: &str) -> Module {
        self.context.create_module(name)
    }
```

On the function we see no liftime parameters, but Module has a lifetime parameter, so what's going on?
Well The lifetimes are elided. This means that ever lifetime parameter here is the same, in other words you could rewrite create_module as:

```
    #[inline]
    pub fn create_module<'a>(&'a self, name: &'a str) -> Module<'a> {
        self.context.create_module(name)
    }
```

This means that if you input a `&'context Context`(which you did) and a `&'static str` then you must get a `Module<'shorter_or_equal_to_context_and_static>`. Obviously `'context` is shorter than `'static`, so the compiler went with `Module<'context>`.

Then you inputed `Module<'context>` to `f`. But f requires a reference to the module of the same length as (or longer) as `'context`. The problem is you declared module after context(which you kinda have to), so you can't get a reference to module that lasts longer than context. The solution is to not require that the reference to module has the same lifetime as the module's template parameter, as you have already discovered with `pub fn f<'ctx, 'a>(_module: &'a Module<'ctx>) where 'ctx: 'a {}`, though I would prefer `pub fn f<'ctx, 'a>(_module: &'a Module<'ctx>)`.